# How I can access SQL database from different domain

Tags: php, mysql, shared-hosting

I'm trying to connect two websites together to share the same Database

```
define('DB_NAME', 'test');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

**The website that have database is on shared server, 5 websites share the same public IP**

I tried to put the public IP in "DB_HOST" but it doesn't work!.

How I can access the website database from outside on a shared server?
When I login into phpmyadmin, the link is encrypted and doesn't show any IP, and query commands are closed.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: To start with, you need find out if the database is accessible from internet at all and no firewall on the server blocks the mysql port. You also need to make sure that the database user you're using can accept requests from other addresses than localhost. It would also help if you expanded on what "doesn't work" means. Do you get any error? Have you checked the servers error log?

Comment: Yes, there is no lock on accessing the database from outside, and the username can access from outside too, the error is page not found if I access the database from link and port, while when I try with php code it says database not exist! it;s like the link to the database is not correct

Comment: @narzan "Page not found" is not an error message related to MySQL databases. It is an error related to websites, like entering the wrong URL. Please [edit] your question to include the full error message you get and the source code you have as a [mcve].